# php mySQL query process array loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, input

My same script works on another page, and the other queries on the same page are using the same connection string. For some reason when I run the 'filled' condition it says my connection string is null. "mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, null given in..." Yet if I run the 'filled2' condition it executes just fine. Can anyone see what I don't?

```
if (isset($_POST['filled'])) {

    function updateRecords($varA,$varB,$varC){
        $updateMyTable = "UPDATE myTable SET colA='$varA', colB=$varB WHERE colC = $varC";
        if (!mysql_query($updateMyTable,$con)) {
            die('Error 1: '. mysql_error());
        } 
    }

    if ( isset( $_POST['inputArray'] ) ) {
        foreach ( $_POST['inputArray'] as $lilVars ) {
            updateRecords($lilVars['inputA'],$lilVars['inputB'],$lilVars['inputC']);
        }
    } 

} elseif (isset($_POST['filled2'])) {

    $sqlAddRecord="INSERT INTO myTable (ColX, ColY, ColZ2) VALUES ($VarX,'$VarY',$VarZ)";
    if (!mysql_query($sqlAddRecord,$con)) {
      die('Error 2: '.mysql_error());
    }

    echo "New Record Added";

}
```

Comment: `$con` probably isn't available in the scope of `updateRecords`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is because you are using $con inside of a function.  You would need to include "global $con" inside your function definition to make it available to the function from the global scope.

```
function updateRecords(...) {
    global $con;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hate to sound really stupid what would that look like script wise? I'm only 3 weeks into php so I've tried a few guesses at what you guys are saying but it isn't doing anything different.

Comment: @ghbarrat  Yes I have revised as that should be the better way to describe it.

Comment: Mike is correct, but use of globals is generally a sign of bad design (see, for example, the spaghetti code that is the Wordpress codebase...), it makes code hard to understand (it's difficult to see where data is changed) and makes testing difficult (global state is hard to control).  You can instead modify your functions to take in a `$con` parameter as well and pass it in when the function is called.

Comment: @El Yobo  This is a good point.  I don't really see what is really even being gained by having this code in a function here anyway.  Typically functions represent some reusable piece of code that might be called from any number of places in the code.  In these cases you would certainly not want to rely on whatever the current value of the variable is in the global scope, but would be best served to actually pass to the function the value you want it to work with, or if you want to modify a global-scope variable, pass it to the function by reference.

Comment: Not sure why I put it in a function. There was some reasoning behind it but no good reason apparently. All suggestions worked and ended up taking it out of the function. Thanks again.